# How can I verify credit card without using any payment gateway?

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway

I have a shopping site. According to requirements, I need to give two options--PayPal payment (if user has PayPal account) and debit/credit card payment. Even if PayPal allows payment for users who don't have a PayPal account, I don't want them to do payments through PayPal. Instead, is there any direct payment for Visa/MasterCard?

Comment: Your question and the description is not clear. Are you checking if there is a Direct credit card acceptance option or are you looking for solution to validate just if a credit card is a valid credit card?

Comment: Looking for Direct credit card acceptance option

Answer (score 0):

PayPal Payments + Direct Credit Card Acceptance is available as part of the new REST APIs as well as the Express Checkout APIs.

Please use any of these products (suggest REST API).